# I'm trying to use JavaScript to insert code syntax into an HTML code tag and then edit the tag with Prism syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, prism

Here's the HTML that needs syntax inserted between the code tags (I took out the less than sign so it would render on the page):

pre> code> id="test" class="language-python"> /code> /pre>

Here's the JavaScript that attempts to insert code syntax between the code tags and render it using Prism.

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "print()";

If I place code between the HTML code tags, the text renders properly with Prism.  When I try to insert code from JavaScript, it doesn't.  I've tried creating a code tag element in JavaScript and changing the className in a variety of ways, and I've tried using the xmp tag.  I can get code to render to the screen from JavaScript using innerHTML, but it's not formatting using Prism.  Any help would be appreciated.

In my HTML page, I have the prism.css and prism.js files below the Bootstrap files in the head.

Comment: could you show the contents of some of these files?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prism.css">
    <script src="prism.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getCode()
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "print()"; 
        }
    </script>
    </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getCode()">Get Code</button>
        <pre><code class="language-python">print()</code></pre>
        <pre><code id="test" class="language-python"></code></pre>
      </div>

Comment: Did you find an answer? stucked with the same issue